# UIActivityTypeCopyToPasteboard How to attach Image and Text

Tags: ios, uiactivityviewcontroller, uiactivity

I'm using the UIActivityViewController, and I have two items of data that I share. One is some text, and the other is an image. When I use the UIActivityTypeCopyToPasteboard, it always just copies the text component and not the image. I thought it might have been based on the order of the items in the array of data, but it makes no difference.

Is there any way to force it to copy the image instead of the text without having to make your own UIActivity?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

[This tutorial](http://www.albertopasca.it/whiletrue/2012/10/objective-c-custom-uiactivityviewcontroller-icons-text/) will help you. Notice the use of `UIActivityItemProvider <UIActivityItemSource>`

Comment: Thanks, but my question was "is there a way to force it to copy the image instead of the text *WITHOUT* having to make your own UIActivity"

Comment: `UIActivityItemProvider` is *NOT* `UIActivity` and it's like, 10 or 20 lines. `UIActivity` is far more complex and for an entirely different purpose.